# Scan epub and pdf to ascertain absence of malware

Tags: epub, pdf

Is it possible to verify the absence of malware in epub and pdf files?.

I'm using a MacBook Air, macOS Catalina, and iPad mini iOS 13. What program can I use?

Answer (score 2):

epub have an html format, is possible to insert malware inside. Any antivirus can check your ebooks and report you if some is infected. 
By other side, if you bought it from a marketplace as Amazon, probably your ebook is virus free. 
If you download it from "other sites"… well, you must assume that "can" be infected, so use any online antivirus to check your files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/). It's an online virus scanner (files, URLs and more). Be sure to check their [terms of service](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002145529-Terms-of-Service) and [Privacy policy](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002168385-Privacy-Policy).